# Check that the changelog and the database are equal

Tags: java, liquibase

We use liquibase to specify the database layout and the changes of it. In development we use liquibase integrated in our Java application to perform the update if necessary.

Because our application does not have the rights to alter the schema in production, liquibase does not run in production. Instead we use liquibase to generate the SQL scripts. These scripts are then executed manually before our application is deployed.

We would like to make sure that the database layout matches to the changelog that corresponds to the application. The SQL scripts create the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and insert the rows like the `update` command of liquibase would do, so the information about the applied changesets is stored in the database.

However I could not find a suitable liquibase method that only checks if the application's changesets and the database layout/`DATABASECHANGELOG` are equal. This method must not attempt to fix that, it should only return true/false. Is there such a method available in the liquibase Java API?

Comment: Are you looking for `liquibase.diff`? Javadoc [here](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/).

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal No, the diff command compares two different databases. I want to compare a given changeset-file and a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the liquibase source code, I found the method that I was looking for:

```
liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(null, null);
```

This is exactly what I wanted it seems to be working fine.